# Cannot find DOM items using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am a newer to using Jest to test react recently. Expecting the result of test code below get `true` instead of `false`:

```
// Login.js

class Login extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <LoginForm
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withRouterAndConnect(
  state => ({
    ...
  }),
  { ... }
)(Login);


// Login.test.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import Login from "./components/module/Login";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<Login />", () => {
  test("renders logo image", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
    expect(wrapper.find('LoginForm').exist().toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have missing `)` in `expect(wrapper.find('LoginForm').exist().toBe(true);`, is it possible to be an issue?

Comment: try importing actual component and find that. wrapper.find(LoginForm)

Comment: Add the missing `)` and importing actual component have the same error, are there any other detail I ignored?